# RMA not working on new EE 1.13 install

Tags: enterprise-1.13, rma

After installing EE 1.13 I get a 404 error when trying to manage RMA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vim app/code/core/Enterprise/Rma/etc/config.xml

On line 196 change:

```
<enterprise_rma>Enterprise_Rma_Adminhtml</enterprise_rma>
```

to:

```
<enterprise_rma before="Mage_Adminhtml">Enterprise_Rma_Adminhtml</enterprise_rma>
```

RMA works then

Comment: Have you reported this to EE support?

Comment: Brent, this works for me without the change. All relevant RMA screens show up. I'm not sure this is your actual problem. Maybe another extension conflicts?

Comment: This was a brand new install?

Comment: I just moved to new dedicated server and this happened, before it was working well.

Comment: This worked for EE 1.11.2.0 as well. Thank you.